# What's the meaning of DISALLOW_FUN in Android's source code?

Tags: android, android-source

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html, we can find a weird string variable named DISALLOW_FUN, which **Specifies if the user is not allowed to have fun.**

However, I cannot understand what it means.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK, it is an [Easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29), along the lines of `GRAVITY_DEATH_STAR_I` and [many other similar jokes in the SDK](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/04/18/is-your-user-a-goat/).

Comment: Laughter, in particular, is strongly discouraged when this value is set to `true`.

Answer (score 33):

It's an attempt to make Android compatible with Windows Phone users.